# Uniform convergence of $f_n:[1,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \, f_n(x):= \frac{\cos(x/n)}{1-e^{-xn}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I showed the pointwise convergence of
$$f_n:[1,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \, f_n(x):= \frac{\cos(x/n)}{1-e^{-xn}}$$ 
with

$$f_n(x)=\frac{\cos(x/n)}{1-\frac{1}{e^{xn}}}
\xrightarrow{n \, \rightarrow \, \infty}
f(x):=\frac{\cos(0)}{1-0}=1.$$

How can I now show whether or not
$f_n$
converges uniformly?

Would

$$0 \le \left| f_n(x)-f(x) \right| = \left| \frac{\cos(x/n)}{1-e^{-xn}}-1 \right| \le \left| \frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{1-e^{-1 \cdot n}}-1 \right| \xrightarrow{n \, \rightarrow \, \infty} |1-1|=0$$

be right to show that it converges uniformly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show uniform convergence you need to show that:

$$ \underset{x\in[1,\pi]}{\sup} \Big\vert f_n(x)- f(x) \Big\vert \rightarrow 0 $$

But since $f(x)\equiv 1$, you need to show that:

$$ \underset{x\in[1,\pi]}{\sup} \Big\vert f_n(x)- 1 \Big\vert \rightarrow 0  $$

It would be enough to find a sequence $0\leq a_n\rightarrow0$ such that:

$$ \underset{x\in[1,\pi]}{\sup} \Big\vert f_n(x)- 1 \Big\vert\leq a_n $$

**Hint:**  Note that $\vert f_n(x)-1\vert$ is bounded from above for all $x$ by:

$$ \frac{\vert 1-\cos(x/n)\vert+\vert e^{-xn}\vert}{\vert 1-e^{-xn}\vert}  $$

Comment: But how can such a sequence $a_n \rightarrow 0$ exist if it has to hold that $x \in [1, \pi]$, so $1 \le x$? Or can the $x$ still be choosen fittingly?

Comment: For example, does $\vert 1-\cos(x/n)\vert$ obtain a maximum in $[ 1,\pi ]$? If you denote this maximal point by $x_n$ , try to compute the value there.

Comment: Would it be right to set $a_n = \frac{\cos 1/n}{1-e^{\pi n}} -1$?

Comment: The $a_n$ you suggested is a function of $x$, $a_n$ needs to be dependent only on $n$. For example, you can bound your suggested size from above by $\frac{\cos(1/n)}{1}-1$.

Comment: Is it? Do you mean the $\pi$ in the denominator that looks like $x$? Anyway, your suggestions works for this exercise I suppose. So, if I understood you correctly, because $|f_n(x)-1| \le a_n = \cos(1/n)-1$, $f_n$ converges uniformly. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you, what I wrote in the last comment is wrong, but I think you get the gist of it. I think that your $a_n$ should be $\frac{\vert 1-\cos(\pi/n) \vert +e^{-n}}{\vert1-e^{-\pi n}\vert}$.